# How to create a dataframe without getting empty values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, numpy

I have been using one algorithm, and also getting the desired output but when i am trying to convert both the outputs to a specific dataframe, i always receive empty dataframes, can anyone please tell where am i going wrong? I just want to save these two list of outputs with their data in a separate dataframe. As you see in my output: Recommended hotel has a list and all other hotels has a list, i want two seperate dataframes thats it.any help would be highly appreciated.Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd


def recommend_hotels(data, weights):

  df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  # Ask the user for the passenger count
  passenger_count = int(input("Enter the number of passengers: "))

  # Calculate the minimum number of rooms needed
  min_rooms_needed = passenger_count

  # Calculate the difference between total room availability and the passenger count
  df['room_diff'] = df['total_rooms'] - min_rooms_needed

  # Filter hotels with higher availability than the passenger count and sort by room availability in ascending order
   df = df[df['room_diff'] >= 0].sort_values(by='total_rooms')

  # If there are no hotels with higher availability, sort by room availability in ascending order
  if df.empty:
    df = data.copy()
    df = df.sort_values(by='total_rooms')

  # Initialize variables to track room assignments
  assigned_rooms = []
  remaining_passengers = passenger_count

  # Assign double rooms first
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    double_rooms_available = row['double_rooms']
    if double_rooms_available > 0:
        assigned_double_rooms = min(double_rooms_available, remaining_passengers // 2)
        remaining_passengers -= assigned_double_rooms * 2
        assigned_rooms.append((row['hotel_name'], assigned_double_rooms, 'double'))

  # Assign single rooms if needed
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if remaining_passengers > 0:
        single_rooms_available = row['single_rooms']
        assigned_single_rooms = min(single_rooms_available, remaining_passengers)
        remaining_passengers -= assigned_single_rooms
        assigned_rooms.append((row['hotel_name'], assigned_single_rooms, 'single'))

  # Recommend hotels based on room assignments
    recommended_hotels = [hotel[0] for hotel in assigned_rooms]

  # Calculate the total number of rooms to book for all passengers
  total_rooms_to_book = min_rooms_needed

  # Create a DataFrame for recommended hotels
   recommended_hotels_df = 
 df[df['hotel_name'].isin(recommended_hotels)].sort_values(by='total_rooms', ascending=False)
recommended_hotels_df
# Print the initial recommendations
print(f"Recommended Hotels: {', '.join(recommended_hotels)}")
print(f"Book {total_rooms_to_book} rooms for {passenger_count} passengers.")

# List unrecommended hotels in descending order of room availability
unrecommended_hotels = set(data['hotel_name']) - set(recommended_hotels)

if unrecommended_hotels:
    unrecommended_df = df[df['hotel_name'].isin(unrecommended_hotels)].sort_values(by='total_rooms', ascending=False)
    #print(f"\nUnrecommended Hotels (Not in Recommended List) in Descending Order of Availability:")
    for index, row in unrecommended_df.iterrows():
        print(f"{row['hotel_name']} - Total Rooms: {row['total_rooms']}")

# List all other hotels that are not in the recommended list
other_hotels = set(data['hotel_name']) - set(recommended_hotels)

print(f"\nAll Other Hotels (Not in Recommended List): {', '.join(other_hotels)}")

# Create a DataFrame for all other hotels that are not in the recommended list
other_hotels_df = df[df['hotel_name'].isin(other_hotels)]

# Define your data and weights
 data = {
'hotel_name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
'single_rooms': [10, 25, 8, 12, 7],
'double_rooms': [35, 18, 44, 110, 6],
'total_rooms': [45, 43, 52, 122, 13],
 }

 weights = {
 'num_hotels': 0.35,
 'transport': 0.3,
 'room_price': 0.15,
 'meals': 0.1,
 'availability': 0.075,
 'rooms': 0.025,
}
other_hotels_df


# Call the recommend_hotels function with your data and weights
recommend_hotels(data, weights)
```

The output that i am getting is:[image]

What i tried is:

```
other_hotels = set(data['hotel_name']) - set(recommended_hotels) # 
   
other_hotels_df =df[df['hotel_name'].isin(other_hotels)].sort_values(by='total_rooms', ascending=False).
```

Expected output:

```
Recommended_df:
 |hotel_name |single_rooms |double_rooms |total_rooms|
 |B|25|18|43|
 |A|10|35|45|
 |C|8|44|52|
 |D |12|110|122|



UnRecommended_df:
 |hotel_name |single_rooms |double_rooms |total_rooms|
 |E|7|6|13|
```

Comment: What do the inputs to the function ```data``` and ```weights``` look like? Could you give some examples

Comment: @renzo21 its just  random, no matter what input we give it it always prints a list. But for my example I used 20 as my passenger number and the algorithm do its job. The weights and the data has been specified already in the code which gives me the specified output. Thank you.

Comment: You don't show how you try to create this *"DataFrame"*. Btw, can you precise how it should look like ?

Comment: We'd have to see an example of ```data``` and ```weights``` and an expected output to help

Comment: @renzo21@Timeless I just edited, please let me know if any other information is required from my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to replace this line (*74 in your code*) :

```
    other_hotels_df = df[df['hotel_name'].isin(other_hotels)]
```

With these two :

```
    other_hotels_df = pd.DataFrame(data).loc[lambda x: x['hotel_name'].isin(other_hotels)]
    
    return recommended_hotels_df[list(data)[:4]], other_hotels_df[list(data)[:4]]
```

Test/Output :

```
Enter the number of passengers:  20 # <-- input value
Recommended Hotels: B, A, C, D
Book 20 rooms for 20 passengers.

All Other Hotels (Not in Recommended List): E
```

---

Then you can unpack the result in two different DataFrames :

```
rec_df, unrec_df = recommend_hotels(data, weights)

>>> print(rec_df)

  hotel_name  single_rooms  double_rooms  total_rooms
3          D            12           110          122
2          C             8            44           52
0          A            10            35           45
1          B            25            18           43

>>> print(unrec_df)

  hotel_name  single_rooms  double_rooms  total_rooms
4          E             7             6           13
```